# ActiveMQ + Spring + DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Extremely poor performance

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I have a DefaultMessageListenerContainer setup with the following configuration:

```
threadServiceListenerContainer(org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer) {
        maxConcurrentConsumers = 10
        concurrentConsumers = 1
        destinationName = 'releaseThread'
        pubSubDomain = false
        connectionFactory = ref("connectionFactory")
        messageListener = ref('threadServiceMessageListener')
    }
```

There are 3000 backlogged messages sitting in the broker. The consumption rate seems to be 2/sec. I've attached JProfiler to the Java node, but it seems the 10 listener threads/consumers are sitting idle at worst, or operating at 1-at-a-time at best.

The consumer processing time does not register with JProfiler. The consumer just adds a value to memcached, and memcached is operating healthily.

It seems that my consumer is just... sitting there...

Any thoughts? I've rebooted the broker, no performance difference. I've rebooted the node, no performance difference.

I'm injecting Map into the broker.

Here's my connectionfactory bean:

```
connectionFactory(org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory, ref("amqConnectionFactory")) {
        exceptionListener = {com.zipwhip.jms.JmsExceptionListener jmsExceptionListener -> }
        sessionCacheSize = 100
    }
    amqConnectionFactory(org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory) {
        brokerURL = 'tcp://localhost:61616'
    }
```

Comment: what version of AMQ are you using?  it sounds like this issue that was fixed in 5.4, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-2754

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend trying couple of things: set producer flow control to false and change dispatch policy. Try to change either or both to see if it helps. We've had our share of performance problems with ActiveMQ (running embedded with OpenEJB) but finally got everything running smoothly.

To change these using activemq.xml use this:

```
<destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
                <policyEntries>
                    <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="false" enableAudit="false" >
                        <dispatchPolicy>
                            <roundRobinDispatchPolicy />
                        </dispatchPolicy>
                    </policyEntry>
                </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
</destinationPolicy>
```

Also, we upgraded from ActiveMQ 4.x to 5.3.1 and we switched from JDBC/journaled persistence to KahaDB persistence.

Comment: I'm actually concerned that i might be trying to funnel too much traffic through 1 connection. Do you guys use the CachingConnectionFactory? Do you have multiple underlying connections?

Comment: we have single producer and multiple consumers (normally). We use J2EE - not Spring - though. One thing we do when sending to activeMQ is setting useAsyncSend to true. Queue connection factory is the default one we get from ActiveMQ (via openejb).